# Gathering data from HTML files

Tags: java, html, web-scraping

As a part of a job, I have to sort through [this page](http://www.ncpublicschools.org/charterschools/schools/by-county/alphabet-county?range=A-E&&alpha1=A&&alpha2=B&&alpha3=C&&alpha4=D&&alpha5=E&&alpha6=) and gather info on the school administrator, the address, and county of each school.  I have done a decent amount of work in java so I figured if I was going to try to make something to do this, it should be in java.

However I haven't done anything like this before, and am a little confused as to where I should start.  If someone could help me with what classes I need to use, and a little information on how I would go about looking through the HTML code to sort through all of this, that would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement a scraper, i.e. an application that scrapers data out of HTML.

I'd start by looking into a decent scraper library, like jsoup (http://jsoup.org/) and see if you can use it to do the job.

In essense you will end up with something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ncpublicschools.org/...").get();
Elements schools = doc.select("div.indenter p span.colorText2 a");
```

Just keep on applying select rules as necessary to collect the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use java.util.regex ;regular expression are useful  and simple to use

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org) it could work quite well for what you want to do. Im using it to develop an application with automated tests, but it would work for you as well.